# Data available ("this") from a template event handler

Tags: meteor

**projects.html**

```
  {{#if projects}}
    {{#each projects}}
      <div class="project-item">
        <div class="project-name">
          {{name}}
        </div>
        <div class="project-settings">
          <span class="rename">Rename</span>
          <span class="edit">Edit</span>
          <span class="delete">
            <!-- Here -->
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
```

**projects.js**

```
  Template.Projects.events({
    "click .project-item .delete": function (e, template) {
      e.preventDefault();
      debugger
      // "this" refers to the specific project
    }
  });
```

In an event handler, I noticed "this" conveniently refers to a specific object inside the template where the event is related to. For example, in this case, the delete button is inside `each projects` block, and the handler for the delete button has `this = some project`. This is convenient, but I'd like to know the scopes and rules more completely. Can someone explain in briefly and point me to the right document?

Answer (score 0):

This is a data context sensitive feature. Basically, there is a lexical scope in spacebars helpers. Have a look at this: http://devblog.me/no-data-context.html

The original pull request is here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/3560